# div.scrollTop not working in code, works in console

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

I have a div with a set height and `overflow : auto`. When I use in my code `div.scrollTop = 0;` it doesn't work, but if I do the same in the console, it works.

```
//here, div is scrolled half way
div.innerHTML = "";
div.scrollTop = 0;  //not working
div.appendChild(new_long_content); 
//here, div is still scrolled
```

Comment: Can you show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//assume we have a `div` with a lot of content and a scrollbar, 
//and the content is scrolled down:

//this case works
div.innerHTML = ""; //content is small, the scrollbar will disappear.
div.appendChild(new_long_content);  //scrollbar reappears and it will have the 
                                    //same position as it had before disappearing: 0.
div.scrollTop = 0;  //px - new content is scrolled up.

//this doesn't work
div.innerHTML = "";  //content is very short so the scrollbar will disappear.
div.scrollTop = 0;   //px - setting scrollTop when scrollbar not in use has no effect.
div.appendChild(new_long_content); //new content is added, scrollbar appears again, 
                                   //but with the old scroll position.

//summary: you should only use scrollTop when scrollbar is visible and after 
//the new content is loaded, because scrollTop affects only the scrollbar directly and the div only indirectly.
```

Comment: So... Is this your answer?

Comment: Well, Your question is too broad. I suggest to add the exact scenario and code your facing error with to your question. And then add a good explanation for the code that works to your answer. It would help the reader understand better.

Comment: @VinodKumar you can see the code in my answer: at first I had the code that doesn't work and by switching the order a bit I made it work. I put here the question and the answer because I couldn't find this answer on SO or Google. I don't expect another answer. You guys are quick! :)

Comment: Yes, I understand your point. You found the answer and you don't need any more answers. Thats a good thing in fact. What I am suggesting is to make it better you have to frame the question and answer in such a way that the non-working part of code resides on the question (Just like a clean question, with wrong code) and a clean answer with a working code and explanation. It will be greater help for others who face similar issue. Hope you understand. Thanks :)